# How to send an 'email address change' email using a custom template

Tags: google-identity

I am trying to brand the "email address change" email using a custom template.

However, I am having trouble figuring how to do this. All the methods to update a user's email, `user.verifyBeforeUpdateEmail` and `user.updateEmail` both automatically send the email with no way of overriding the default behaviour.

I am hoping someone has managed to achieve this customisation and can point me in the right direction.

I have tried updating the template provided by Google Identity Platform/Firebase Auth but the template is non editable. The documentation, correctly, states this is not possible but without any way to override the default behaviour I don't see any other way to customise the email template.

Thanks in advance.